# How does mfcc feature size affect recurent neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, mfcc, librosa

So I'm learning machine learning and wanted to know how does mfcc feature size affect on RNN (Recurent Neural Network)?

With librosa I extracted mfcc and then delta coefficients and after that I get array of dimension [13, sound_length]

The code of extracting mfcc and delta coefficients with python: (y - sound file data, sr - length of y)

```
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=13)
mfcc_delta = librosa.feature.delta(mfcc, axis=0, order=1)
```

So theoretically if I want to train network with this kind of data and with data where n_mfcc=39. Who would be better and why? (Ignore all other hyper parameters) I just want to know theoretics of how this parameter affect RNN.

Comment: I don't think the delta features (first-order derivative, essentially) are necessary as the RNN should be able to learn them on its own. They are probably more important for hidden Markov models (HMM).

Comment: Hello @Nikas were you able to use the mfcc to feed to RNN? anychance you could share your code snippets?thank you

Answer (score 6):

[MFCCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) are coefficients of the [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) of a [Mel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale)-scaled (non-linear) spectrum. In other words, they capture the amplitudes of periodic changes in the Mel spectrum. In music analysis this is often used to describe the [timbre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre) of a piece of music. The lower the index of the coefficient, the lower the frequency (of periodic change in the Mel spectrum).

Simply put: The lower indices/coefficients are usually more important.

The same is the case in the JPEG image file format and MP3—higher DCT coefficients are discarded, as they describe higher frequencies that often aren't considered important.

So fewer coefficients mean you can use a smaller RNN. However, you will loose the information contained in those higher frequencies (which, as stated above, often aren't regarded very important). It's a game of diminishing returns: At some point more coefficients just mean more input, but not necessarily better results.

AFAIK, in music information retrieval ([MIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_information_retrieval)), the first 13 coefficients are usually used. But I have also seen papers using the first 20.

Before it was used in MIR, MFCCs were used in speech recognition.

See [B. Logan. "Mel frequency cepstral coefficients for music modeling." In International Symposium on Music Information Retrieval (ISMIR 2000), 2000.](ftp://gatekeeper.dec.com/pub/dec/CRL/publications/logan/musicir_paper.pdf)

Or [McFee, Brian, and Gert RG Lanckriet. "Heterogeneous Embedding for Subjective Artist Similarity." ISMIR 2009, 2009.](http://eceweb.ucsd.edu/~gert/papers/hesas.pdf)

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is a really nice answer, particularly the first paragraph!